# Can an AppWidget layout use two Activity?

Tags: android

Can I use two classes on an Android appwizard?

I want to handle each event in AppWidget by Button.
However, AppWidget does not inherit Activity and is not possible.

I use RemoteView.
first Way: setOnClickPendingIntent function using RemoteView, but function is used to display the screen.

All I want to use is simply pressing a button and counting the number on the button one by one.

In Activity, we know that you can handle click events using the findViewById function. I think the content of event handling can be done with the setText() function.

I could not find data on the Internet.
So I thought it.

One AppWidget work two Activity.

new_app_widget .xml -> NewAppWidget
-> ButtonClick

Therefore, an additional class is created and inherite activity.
class use findViewById function and click events.
but does not function.

Activity was also registered in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
    <activity android:name=".ButtonClick">

    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".NewAppWidget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

`